# How to convert images to video with ffmpeg api not commands?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert images(as jpg) to video(as mp4),
but looking up at the ffmpeg docs, I just found command lines as follow
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg

Does anyone know the api with c or c++ code? Thanks.

Comment: See `doc/examples` in the FFmpeg source code.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
Open output file;
Open output code;
while(input files remain) {
    Open input file;
    Decode input frame;
    Give decoded frame a timestamp;
    Encode frame;
    Write frame to output file;
}

Flush encode;
Close output file;
```

Do the steps in order. Im sure you'll have question as you implement this. When you have a question, Open a new topic on stack overflow with the code you have so far with a specific problem, and what you have already tried.